# comparing array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, ruby-1.9.2

I have array of hashes `[{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}, {"a"=> 3, "b" => 4}, {"a" => 5, "b" => 6}]`. Now I need to compare all the hashes with each other, ie, compare 1st hash with 2nd and 3rd hash, and 2nd with 3rd hash. If anybody has any idea, please let me know!

Comment: Maybe it's obvious to others but you should provide a tag for the programming language you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `rails console` :

```
irb(main):001:0> array = [{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}, {"a"=> 3, "b" => 4}, {"a" => 5, "b" => 6}]
irb(main):002:0> 0.upto(array.length-2) do |index|
irb(main):003:1* (index+1).upto(array.length-1) do |index2|
irb(main):004:2* puts "array[#{index}][a]-array[#{index2}][a] is : #{array[index]["a"]-array[index2]["a"]}"
irb(main):005:2> puts "array[#{index}][b]-array[#{index2}][b] is : #{array[index]["b"]-array[index2]["b"]}"
irb(main):006:2> end
irb(main):007:1> end
array[0][a]-array[1][a] is : -2
array[0][b]-array[1][b] is : -2
array[0][a]-array[2][a] is : -4
array[0][b]-array[2][b] is : -4
array[1][a]-array[2][a] is : -2
array[1][b]-array[2][b] is : -2
=> 0
```

And that's how you can compare them. I've used **minus (-)**, you may want to use **AND (&)** then for that you have to put "&" symbol at the place of "-" else you can do whatever operation you wants to perform on it... :)

Answer (score 4):

Rails has class Hash with `diff` method which returns the hash difference

```
{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}.diff("a"=> 3, "b" => 4) # { "a" => 1, "b" => 2 }
```

Look also at `merge` method, it could be useful in your case

Answer (score 0):

rails has a nice little hash.diff method that can be easily ported into Ruby